# Xamarin: Distribution on Play Store/App Store/Windows Store with Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: xamarin, google-play, app-store, windows-store, visual-studio-2015

Am I allowed to distribute my xamarin app created in visual studio 2015 community edition on Play Store / App Store / Windows Store commercially? 
Or do I have to buy any extra licenses?

And what about non-commercial apps?
Are there any restrictions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there is nothing to buy from *Microsoft/Xamarin* to allow distribution of an iOS/Android/UWP app. There is of course **developer enrollment fees** from Apple, Google, & Microsoft that have to be paid to allow apps to be uploaded to their respective stores.

Comment: @SushiHangover But on the xamarin webside you can see that with Visual Studio 2015 community edition you can just develop open-source software. Only the professional edition provides no usage restrictions. Im a little confused...:/

Comment: Where are you seeing that? Have a link?

Comment: @SushiHangover https://store.xamarin.com/ - Or do I understand something wrong :/

Comment: Are you a group of more than 5 developers? No? Then you are considered a **Small team** (assuming less than $1M USD annual revenues, less then 250 PCs or users, etc...). Are you considered an **Enterprise**? Then you would need to purchase VS Enterprise licenses... Consult the `Visual Studio licensing white paper` for details :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx

Comment: @SushiHangover But why does it say "OSS Development " (At Community Edition)? Maybe i understand / translate something wrong (im german)

Comment: Within the Visual Studio license, **IF** you are developing OSI-licenced open source software, you are allowed to use Visual Studio (and thus Xamarin) free of restrictions no matter how many users there are. *Totally separate* is the Small Team definition and has nothing to do with open-source software. A **Small Team** is also allowed to use Visual Studio to develop applications unrestricted, but if you fall into the **Enterprise** level, licenses have to purchased. **If you have Visual Studio already installed, there should be a german language VS License Agreement available.**

Comment: @SushiHangover ok, now I understand :) Thanks's a lot!